# Replace Using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a modal form that pops-up on a button press event.  The form currently appends the input value from the textbox to the end of the current cells value.

I am appending to the end of the current value like so

```
row.cells[1].innerHTML = row.cells[1].innerHTML + ' - ' + $('#<%=txtNewVal.ClientID %>').val();
```

Is it possible to take the new value `$('#<%=txtNewVal.ClientID %>').val()` and replace a value in the current string?

For example - let's say that `row.cells[1].innerHTML` = "Bilge Water And Muskrat Soup" and the `$('#<%=txtNewVal.ClientID %>').val()` reads Pumpkin Pie

Using JQuery could I replace `Muskrat Soup` with `Pumpkin Pie`?  I.E. a replace string from the current value with the new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace` and rebind table cell like this.

```js
if ($('td').html().indexOf("Muskrat Soup") > 0) {
$('td').html($('td').html().replace("Muskrat Soup", "Pumpkin Pie"));

} else {
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Bilge Water And Muskrat Soup</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```